# 'c̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟' character in Zalgo in Chrome's Google history

Tags: google-chrome, unicode, zalgo

I have managed to get a `c̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟` (from Zalgo) in Chrome's history and now, any search that starts with a `c` is typed in the address bar I get `c̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟` instead.

How to I clear this?

e.g.

`c̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟alender`
`c̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟upcakes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A. Turn off the Suggestion Service
>
> 1. Click the Wrench icon, then select Options
> 2. In Under the Hood tab at the Privacy section, unchecked Use a suggestion service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the
>    address bar.
> 3. Close
>
> B. Zeroing the Pop Up Count using the command line This would trick
> the address bar to display zero results.
>
> 1. Go to Google Chrome icon, the one that you used to launch Chrome, right-click on it then select Properties
> 2. In Shortcut tab at Target, add a --omnibox-popup-count=0 (do not insert inside the quotation marks)
> 3. OK
>
> C. Changing the Search Engine's URL Google Chrome by default used a
> customized Google's search URL that would allow to show search and URL
> suggestions, we can change it by following this format:
>
> 1. Go to Wrench icon, select Options
> 2. In Basics tab at Default search, click Manage.
> 3. Select Google in the list then click Edit
> 4. Highlight the URL then replace it with this new one: http://www.google.com.ph/search?hl=en&q=%s
> 5. OK
>
> D. If you don't want to clear "all" your history, you can do the
> following:
>
> 1. Type chrome:history into the address bar.
> 2. Search for the specific history entry.
> 3. Click Edit items on the upper right corner - checkbox will appear in front of the history entries.
> 4. Select the checkbox for the entries that you'd like to delete.
> 5. Click Remove selected items.
> 6. Click Done removing items to complete.

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xooGdnKM38Y%5B1-25-false%5D)